# WP8 App localization does not working

Tags: windows-phone-8, localization

I'm working on windows phone 8 application. I have a lot of multilanguage resources, but when I have tried to test my app on "ru-RU" localization - it loads in English only.

I have tried to set
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture 
      = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
      = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
manually, but when i check  AppResources.ResourceLanguage it will return "en"

When I set CultureInfo("ru") - everything works fine

Comment: Have you tried to change Language and Region of the phone?

Comment: yes, when i choose Russia and Russian - it shows in english

Answer (score 0):

You have to set all supported locals in the csproj. Example: `<SupportedCultures>de-DE;es-ES;</SupportedCultures>`.

[Localizing a Windows Phone app Step by Step](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/localizing-a-windows-phone-app-step-by-step)